# Second Shifting Theorem

Tags: laplace-transform

I need to find the Laplace transform of the following function $\frac{1}{4} tu(t-7)$  using the second shifting theorem

My working is as follows

$\frac{1}{4} tu(t-7) = e^{-7s} L(\frac{1}{4}(t+7))$

$= e^{-7s} (\frac{1}{4s^2}+ \frac{7}{4s})$

Is this correct or do I need to do more working/completely find a new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(t)=\frac{1}{4} tu(t-7)$$
Rewrite it as:
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{4}( (t-7)u(t-7)+7u(t-7))$$
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{4} (t-7)u(t-7)+\frac{7}{4}u(t-7)$$
Apply the Shift Theorem.
$$F(s)=\dfrac {e^{-7s}} {4s^2}+\dfrac {7e^{-7s}}{4s}$$
$$F(s)=\dfrac {e^{-7s}} {4s}\left(\dfrac 1s+  7\right)$$

Comment: I got this as an answer e^-7s[(1-21s)/(4s^2)] + (7e^(7s))/4s. Is this correct?

Comment: The exponential should be negative $e^{-7s}$ @KatL  and first term should be $e^{-7s}\dfrac 14\dfrac 1 {s^2}$  your second term is nearly correct ...just exponential should be $e^{-7s}$

Comment: I added some lines @KatL

Comment: Thankyou @Aryadeva This makes so much more sense now

Comment: You are welcome. Yes before to apply the second shift theorem you have to rewrite the function @KatL